# Could not find a declaration file for module in React Js

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

[VB CODE code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4dzU.png)
Hi everyone! I am writing a single application using REACT and when I was trying to use import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

I am getting the following error:

Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router-dom'. 'c:/Users/paula/first-app/node_modules/react-router-dom/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/react-router-dom` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-router-dom';`ts(7016)

I did install "npm install react-router-dom", but can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Please include your code as text in the question. Images are too hard to read and don't allow copy and paste for testing.

Comment: If you are using typescript with react, try to install `npm install --save @types/react-router-dom`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like the error message says, you also need to install the types of react-router-dom:

```
npm install @types/react-router-dom -D
```

or

```
yarn add @types/react-router-dom -D
```

Comment: Thank you, I did that and it doesn't show the warning anymore, but my code still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of using **<BrowserRouter>** use
```

```
    <Router>
         <Switch>
                 <Route path="/" component={componentName}/>
          </Switch>
    </Router>
```

avoid **div** inside router